# How do I make an info bar at the top of the page like on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: user-interface, usability

Im seriously jealous of the person who designed this website and in particular the 'info' bar at the top of the page that notifies you every so often.

I very much want this on my website, does anyone know of a downloadable script that resembles something like this? (php)

An answer from the stackoverflow design team would be nice! ;)

Comment: C'mon, folks. Belongs on Meta? "I saw this technique used on SO" doesn't make asking about how to create it a Meta question. SO's just being used as an example - you wouldn't vote to close if it said "I saw this on Amazon/Google/Fark and was wondering how it was done".

Comment: This doesn't belong on meta. It's asking about a specific programming-issue.

Comment: ok Ive gotta run, thanks for looking at my question and I'll give somone a green tick in the morning!

Comment: I edited the title into tthe form of a question, should help prevent more close votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will largely be done with jQuery. It's just a matter of periodically querying the server:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.post("getUpdates.php", function(response){
    showInfoBar(response);
  });
}, 10000);
```

That would request updates every 10 seconds. You could do this once the page loads too. As for the PHP code in getUpdates.php:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["userid"]))
  die("You are not logged in");

$updates = getUpdatesForUser($_SESSION["userid"]);
if ($updates) {
  print json_encode($updates);
} else {
  print "No updates";
}
```

As for the get-updates, you can do that as a table in your database:

```
userid |         time        | updatemsg
-------------------------------------------------------------
   28  | 2009-08-21 12:53:02 | You've received the 'uber' badge.
```

Getting a users updates is as easy as querying this table for all new updates. You could create a field to indicate when an update has been sent, and should not be sent again.

This is all very thrown-together, but should give you a very basic idea of how to accomplish it.

Comment: ok and getUpdates would also notify new users to check out the FAQ, you think getUpdates would be a log of sorts? Running off a database?

Comment: ok I realise it was sort of a basic question but Im just thinking about future updates on my site, it certainly helps knowing that its not too much code on the backend. cheers

Answer (score 3):

View -> Source

```
            <div id="topbar">

                <div id="hlinks">
                    <a href="/users/recent/144496"><img src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/replies-off.png" width="15" height="10" title="you have no new replies"></a>
                    <a href="/users/144496/martin" >Martin</a>&nbsp;<span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score">741</span><span title="9 bronze badges"><span class="badge3">&#9679;</span><span class="badgecount">9</span></span>
<span class="link-separator">|</span>

                    <a href="/users/logout?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f1320043%2fthe-stackoverflow-info-bar-at-the-top-of-the-page">logout</a>
<span class="link-separator">|</span>

                    <a href="/about">about</a> <span class="link-separator">|</span> <a href="/faq">faq</a>
                </div>
                <div id="hsearch">
                    <form id="search" action="/search" method="get">
                    <div>
                        <input name="q" class="textbox" tabindex="1" onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" type="text" maxlength="80" size="28" value="search">

                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Then check out the CSS.

Comment: nah i mean the 'info' bar, the one that tells you 'are you new here?' when you log out

Comment: so since your question is vague ... I get -1 ??? makes sense to me ...

Comment: He gave the wrong block, but the idea is the same. You can view the source to find the info bar code. (Well, unless the jQuery code is modifying the DOM and removing the elements completely and not simply making it appear and disappaer (w/ animation) ).

Comment: I didnt vote you down, it was specific enough that 4 other people got me. Martin you've helped me before on a few problems, im going to even you out!

Comment: thanks @bluedaniel ... my comment should say "the question" not your ... just when I see the gray bar on top, I think of that as an info bar since it contains more info than the "first time here" bar

Answer (score 1):

It's a million times easier than it looks.

You just use jQuery, have a div that is width 100%, left : 0; top : 0; and then show it with some jQuery animation function.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same functionality with [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) framework.
Its really easy to do.

Comment: Amazing. I got -1 for correct answer.

Comment: Agreed, @Sorantis.  +1 to compensate for the downvote.